# Opencart www and without www

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have the problem on Opencart.
in my config.php file, defined define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/');
in front end, http://example.com work well, but http://www.example.com not working

But, http://example.com/admin and http://wwww.example.com/admin is all working well.
it's strange.
This is .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks



RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

RewriteBase /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit your config URL to match the following

Public Config

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.quickee.lk/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.quickee.lk/');
```

Admin Config

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.quickee.lk/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.quickee.lk/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.quickee.lk/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.quickee.lk/');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The issue is www and not www. I resolved the problem. But it's work around. I used .htaccess to redirect not www to link have www. Do you have the better way?

Comment: Normally when you just change this in the config file it does the redirect for you. You can maybe try to do this in cPanel as a domain redirect I doubt it's possible but I'll check it out on my server and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. .htaccess same as config on apache. If we config on apache is better.

Comment: Have you set seo url in opencart settings as yes.  If you want the mod rewrites might as well do that too